# MySQL: translate id's to values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table that contains alot of columns with ids(keys) corresponding to other tables.
for example, I have a table of cars that were sold

```
[table of cars that were sold]
(
  car_make_id
, car_engine_id
, car_model_id
, car_radio_id
, buyer_id
, seller_id
, car_tittle_id
, sale_price
)
```

with each one of the id  fields having another table containing the id and name like:

```
[another table]
(
  car_make_id
, car_engine_id
, car_model_id
, car_radio_id
, buyer_id
, seller_id
, car_tittle_id
, sale_price
)

[and another table]
(
  car_make
, car_make_id
)

[and another table]
(
  car_title
, car_title_id
)
```

etc,...with each table named `car_lookup`, `car_model_lookup`,...

Is there anyway to join all these simply without writing a million subqueries. The are millions of entries in this table, and each additional join costs alot in terms of time. I am looking for a fast and efficient way of comparing this data against another table that doesn't have id's, but just the names. lets say I have a list of compatible radios that would have(make, model, engine, radio) and I want to have a list of all the sellers names who sold cars with incompatible radios, and how many incompatible sales they made.

I have been doing stuff like this in perl, but it can take hours to run. so I am looking for something that can be done in mysql.

ps: the car stuff is just an example, I don't actually work with cars, but it illustrates the problem I am having. I cannot change the way the database is set up either, due to a large number of code that already queries the data.

Thanks

Comment: please post some sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need *some* way of telling the database which tables to pull names from for each ID.

If this kind of query is too slow, perhaps you can optimize your database or MySQL server to be able to fill these JOIN statements faster. Try increasing cache sizes (especially if your server has much RAM) and make sure you have key indexing on those lookup tables.

```
SELECT car_make, car_engine, car_model, car_radio,
       buyer, seller, car_title, sale_price FROM cars_sold
JOIN car_make_lookup USING (car_make_id)
JOIN car_engine_lookup USING (car_engine_id)
JOIN car_title_lookup USING (car_title_id)
JOIN car_model_lookup USING (car_model_id)
JOIN car_radio_lookup USING (car_radio_id)
JOIN buyer_lookup USING (buyer_id)
JOIN seller_lookup USING (seller_id)
JOIN car_title_lookup USING (car_title_id)
```